# How do i optimize below code so that it can accept any array size and give me the result

Tags: java, arrays

The below code displays the subarrays of the given array. But if i increase array size by one the below code fails to display all the
 subarrays, to make it successfully display all the arrays i need to
 add one more for loop. So how can i optmize code so that it display
 all the subarrays dynamically by not depending on the array size.

```
public class Subarrays {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr=new int[] {1,-2,4,-5,1};
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("["+arr[i]+"]");
            for(int j=0; j<arr.length-(i+1); j++) {
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("["+arr[i]+","+arr[i+1]+"]");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("["+arr[i]+","+arr[i+1]+","+arr[i+2]+"]");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-3; i++) {
            System.out.println("["+arr[i]+","+arr[i+1]+","+arr[i+2]+","+arr[i+3]+"]");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length-4; i++) {
            System.out.println("["+arr[i]+","+arr[i+1]+","+arr[i+2]+","+arr[i+3]+","+arr[i+4]+"]");
        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void printAllSubArrays(int[] arr) {
    for (int len = 1; len <= arr.length; len++) {
        for (int from = 0; from + len <= arr.length; from++) {
            System.out.print('[');

            for (int i = from; i < from + len; i++) {
                if (i != from)
                    System.out.print(',');
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }

            System.out.println(']');
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
printAllSubArrays(new int[] { 1, -2, 4, -5, 1 });
```

**Output:**

```
[1]
[-2]
[4]
[-5]
[1]
[1, -2]
[-2, 4]
[4, -5]
[-5, 1]
[1, -2, 4]
[-2, 4, -5]
[4, -5, 1]
[1, -2, 4, -5]
[-2, 4, -5, 1]
[1, -2, 4, -5, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a  bunch for replying but i need to use array only to achieve the result

Comment: Thanks a lotttt for responding @aleg.cherednik:)

Comment: I just want to ask one thing like. How did you analysed the problem to write this algorithm?. bcoz when every i try to write a program i analyse but i coulnd't able to figure out the exacty solution programtically but logically i understand it.

Comment: I am struggling to ask something which is in my heart. I really wanted to write algorithms like the one which you wrote but i cannot figure it out on how to write. For example if i want to print integer in reverse way i couldn't able to think off any problematical solution but when i see in website i can understand the program, same with sorting, recursion, subarray and etc. If i am learning algorithms which are written by others when will i write a algorithm of my own and where i am lagging.

Comment: @aleg.cherednik.  Please brother help me if you understand my problem, else never mind. Thanks

Comment: I cant help you. This is theoretical basis and years of practice. Try to solve as much problems as you can from sites like hackerrank.com

Comment: Okay bro. Thank you :).